# Magento - Fatal Error - Website not working

Tags: fatal-error, magento-1.8

It is a fresh Magento installation. The store opens up initially. If you navigate to other page or take any action, I am getting this error.

Fatal error: Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract::getMessages() [mage-core-model-session-abstract.getmessages]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded before unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/wwwdomac/public_html/aplikacija/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php on line 215

Magento CE 1.8.1.0 Apache version 2.2.22 PHP version 5.3.14 MySQL version 5.5.40-cll Operating system linux

I am not able to fix this issue.

Any help in fixing issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to Magento not being able to access the .htaccess file in the root directory.

In your httpd.conf file you need to change the setting `Allow Override none` to `Allow Override all`